# How do I register an imported component in a Vue SFC to satisfy the eslint-plugin-vue vue/no-unregistered-components rule?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, eslint

I'm new to the Vue ecosystem and am trying to get clean `eslint-plugin-vue` results on a test project. In the test `Home.vue` file below, I'm getting a warning: `The "HelloWorld" component has been used but not registered (vue/no-unregistered-components)`. What's the syntactically correct way to clean this up?

Is this a limitation of the [vue/no-unregistered-components](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-unregistered-components.html) ESLint rule itself that it does not recognize the `export default class Home extends Vue {}` and `@Component(...)` syntax?

```html
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout column align-center>
      <!-- ESLint warning "The "HelloWorld" component has been used but not registered. (eslint vue/no-unregistered-components)" occurs on the HelloWorld element below -->
      <HelloWorld
        quote="Hello world!"
        author="Jiminy Cricket"
      />
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

*Update:*
I'm adding my `.eslintrc.js` file here and further tool versions below.

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  /* ESLint + Prettier config */
  extends: [
    'plugin:vue/base',
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'plugin:vue/strongly-recommended',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended',
    '@vue/prettier',
    '@vue/prettier/@typescript-eslint'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    'vue/no-unregistered-components': [
      'warn',
      { ignorePatterns: ['v(-\\w+)+', 'router-link', 'router-view'] }
    ],
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'warn' : 'off',
    'space-before-function-paren': [
      'error',
      {
        anonymous: 'always',
        named: 'never',
        asyncArrow: 'always'
      }
    ]
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      // do not apply typescript rules to *.config.js
      files: ['*.config.js'],
      plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
      rules: {
        // Alas, there is currently no way to turn off all @typescript-eslint/* rules for a *.js file
        '@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires': 0
      }
    },
    {
      // enable the rule specifically for TypeScript files
      files: ['*.ts', '*.tsx'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': ['error']
      }
    },
    {
      // how to enable the rule only for Typescript *.vue files???
      //files: ['*.vue?lang=ts'],
      files: ['*.vue'],
      rules: {
        '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': ['warn']
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With this the command `npx vue-cli-service lint --no-fix src\views\Home.vue` (to lint a single file) yields:

```html
warning: The "HelloWorld" component has been used but not registered (vue/no-unregistered-components) at src\views\Home-min.vue:4:7:
  2 |   <v-container fluid>
  3 |     <v-layout column align-center>
> 4 |       <HelloWorld
    |       ^
  5 |         quote="Hello world!"
  6 |         author="Jiminy Cricket"
  7 |       />

1 warning found.
```

The same warning appears in VSCode when I have the `dbaeumer.vscode-eslint` extension enabled. I'm running `eslint 6.8.0`, `@vue/cli-service 4.5.9`, and `eslint-plugin-vue 7.11.1`.

Comment: If you are using TypeScript - you may need to configure ESLint to support the syntax - https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/eslint-for-typescript/

Comment: Thanks... I have done that. That is to say, ESLint Typescript rules are being applied to the `<script>`  block through my `.eslintrc.js` configuration. I don't think It's an issue with the Typescript itself, but rather with checking the `<template>` against the `<script>` code.

Comment: Are you using a Vue CLI scaffolded project? I can't reproduce this error. What IDE are you using?

Comment: @tony19, I've just added more details of my `.eslintrc.js` and tool versions. I manually upgraded  the `eslint-plugin-vue` plugin to the latest v7.11.1.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually register the component in your `components` section? You would need to register the component after importing it, e.g.

```js
<template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-layout column align-center>
      <HelloWorld  
        quote="Hello world!"
        author="Jiminy Cricket"
       >
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from '@/components'

export default {

...

components: {
  HelloWorld
},

...

</script>

...
```

Furthermore, I suspect you want to `v-bind` the author and quote props to use them in the child.

Comment: The issue is specifically with the `@Component({...` and `export default class Home extends Vue {}` syntax. The syntax you have above works fine.

Comment: I see. Without having tested, I suspect the problem lies within your syntax. As of now, the `class` you would like to register as component doesn't have any properties. As such, it cannot find the `HelloWorld` component you used. I suggest rewriting your code so it says ```@Component 
export default class Home extends Vue {
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}```

Comment: The `export default class Home extends Vue {}` syntax is valid--the Single File Component works fine. The syntax is used in Vue SFCs produced by others, so I don't want to rewrite it because among other things it would defeat the purpose of reusing others' components. I strongly suspect that the root of this particular issue is the `vue/no-unregistered-components` ESLint rule itself not being aware of the `extends Vue {}` and `@Component` syntax. But I haven't gotten any responses on that point.